# What does the destructor of ATL's CAccessToken actually do?

Tags: windows, winapi, atl

CAccessToken is fairly poorly documented, it's destructor is simply documented as:

"Frees all allocated resources."

I'd like to know how true this is, for example, if I Attach() to a token I obtained with OpenProcessToken() will it CloseHandle() for me?  I presume it will since it has no Close() method.  Also, what will happen if I call "LoadUserProfile()", will the profile be unloaded when the CAccessToken goes out of scope?  I notice that it has no "UnloadUserProfile()" method....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CAccessToken` source code is there with Visual Studio:

- \VC\atlmfc\include\atlsecurity.h
- \VC\atlmfc\include\atlsecurity.inl

Class destructor calls `Clear` and does `UnloadUserProfile` and `CloseHandle`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks!  I only saw the .h file, I didn't spot the existance of the .inl file.